# Custom Trustpilot invite to review email

Tags: html, email, html-email, trustpilot

I am trying to write an email to send to customers to invite them, after a purchase, to review the website.

The email contains some stars that once clicked, sends them to the trust pilot page, however, the stars on the trust pilot page are not completed.

When you view a trustpilot page and select a star rating ie 3 stars, you are then taken to:- https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.website.co.uk?stars=3 and the three stars are selected with the text area available to write the review.

My email template does the same thing... If you select 3 stars it will take you to https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=3, for 4 stars it will take you to https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=4 and so on.

The difference being that the stars are not highlighted and the text boxes are not shown so the customer then has to select the rating again.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 275px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 50px; direction: rtl;" dir="rtl">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top;" width="55" class="star-wrapper" lang="x-star-wrapper">
            <div style="display: block; text-align: center; float: left;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;">
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=5" class="star" target="_blank" lang="x-star-divbox" style="color: #FFCC00; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;" tabindex="1">
                    <div lang="x-empty-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block;">☆</div>
                    <div lang="x-full-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block; width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none; height: 0; max-height: 0;">★</div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=5" class="star-number" target="_blank" lang="x-star-number" style="font-family: sans-serif;color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; display: block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">5</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top" width="55" class="star-wrapper" lang="x-star-wrapper">
            <div style="display: block; text-align: center; float: left;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;">
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=4" class="star" target="_blank" lang="x-star-divbox" style="color: #FFCC00; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;" tabindex="2">
                    <div lang="x-empty-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block;">☆</div>
                    <div lang="x-full-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block; width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none; height: 0; max-height: 0;">★</div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=4" class="star-number" target="_blank" lang="x-star-number" style="font-family: sans-serif;color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; display: block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">4</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top" width="55" class="star-wrapper" lang="x-star-wrapper">
            <div style="display: block; text-align: center; float: left;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;">
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=3" class="star" target="_blank" lang="x-star-divbox" style="color: #FFCC00; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;" tabindex="3">
                    <div lang="x-empty-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block;">☆</div>
                    <div lang="x-full-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block; width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none; height: 0; max-height: 0;">★</div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=3" class="star-number" target="_blank" lang="x-star-number" style="font-family: sans-serif;color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; display: block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">3</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top" width="55" class="star-wrapper" lang="x-star-wrapper">
            <div style="display: block; text-align: center; float: left;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;">
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=2" class="star" target="_blank" lang="x-star-divbox" style="color: #FFCC00; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;" tabindex="4">
                    <div lang="x-empty-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block;">☆</div>
                    <div lang="x-full-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block; width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none; height: 0; max-height: 0;">★</div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=2" class="star-number" target="_blank" lang="x-star-number" style="font-family: sans-serif;color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; display: block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">2</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 0;vertical-align: top" width="55" class="star-wrapper" lang="x-star-wrapper">
            <div style="display: block; text-align: center; float: left;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;">
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=1" class="star" target="_blank" lang="x-star-divbox" style="color: #FFCC00; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;" tabindex="5">
                    <div lang="x-empty-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block;">☆</div>
                    <div lang="x-full-star" style="margin: 0;display: inline-block; width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none; height: 0; max-height: 0;">★</div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/www.supplementgenie.co.uk?stars=1" class="star-number" target="_blank" lang="x-star-number" style="font-family: sans-serif;color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px; text-decoration: none; display: block;height: 50px;width: 55px;overflow: hidden;line-height: 60px;border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">1</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone knows how to have the email auto populate the trustpilot form that would be great.

Comment: Have you spoken to their support team? They would be the best people to talk to about this.

Comment: I've not, but my understanding is that I should most likely need to take out a payed membership which would offer this type of functionality, I'm tight fisted and would rather find a way myself lol.but I suppose it doesn't hurt to ask

Comment: Ahh I see, fair enough. Do you have a link to any documentation that mentions this functionality? I can't find anything after a quick search

Comment: I've looked as well, nothing. They offer a plugin but it only seems to be for ecommerce and its not an ecommerce store I need it for :-(

Comment: Ahh, so was it something you picked up from the url and hoped it would work or have you seen it work?

Comment: Yeah basically based on the premise that the stars=x gives the rating but thinking about it, there must be JS or equivalent at work.

However,I know it can be done as I have seen it done, but when I checked earlier the link is different, a random string of letters and numbers between /evaluate/ and /www.website.com

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that to make the form appear you need to set the referrer to

```
https://uk.trustpilot.com/evaluate/<<website>>?stars=1?utm_medium=trustbox&utm_source=MicroReviewCount
```